# Hibernate: entity version number

Tags: hibernate, version

I have an entity *e1* and create a new entity *e2*. I do:

```
E2 e2 = new E2();
e2.setE1(e1);
save(e2);
```

*e2* is created correctly in the database but the version number of *e1* is also incremented even though *e1* itself wasn't changed. Is that the correct behaviour or is there a problem somewhere such as my equals method?

Comment: The answer to this is no, if only the child has changed then the parent should not have its version number increased. My problem was:

    List childEntities = dao.getChildEntities();
    parentEntity.setChildEntitits(childEntities)

when I should have gotten the parent entity with the childEntities from the DAO in one go. By explicitly setting the child entities on the parentEntity it was changed and so Hibernate updated the version number.

Comment: I don't get it. Calling `parentEntity.setChildEntitits(childEntities)` caused the change and the version number to increase, right? Secondly, if this is the correct answer to your question, it is fine to submit this as an answer and accept it, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer